# Got "parsererror" when trying to using Ajax call REST Service

Tags: ajax, rest

I have been puzzled by this question for almost a week and still not able to get it solved.

The problem is while using **JS Ajax** calling a `REST GET` method, but I always got

> parser error

However it's working fine for Firefox's `REST` Client

Check the Code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/t5k9j/40/).

Answer (score 0):

The URL http://wally.pythonanywhere.com/test/ is not producing a valid JSONP. Valid JSONP response should look like your json data wrapped in a function invocation. Visit [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) doc for more details.

The actual error your code facing is "jQuery18308228800671640784_1374132969407 was not called". This is because of the invalid JSONP response.

Comment: Thanks abhidsm, I got it fixed